# css line-height property not working (specificity)

Tags: html, css

Here is my website page: [Broken Line-Height property for CSS](http://studentweb.ewu.edu/jhazel/work.html)

Broken section in background red.

I am viewing in chrome.  I applied a line-height of 1.4em to the

element, and then on this particular page set the line-height for the .zinecover p to line-height of 1em.  Of course it is not getting applied for some reason.

I used chrome inspector to view the Matched CSS rules, it shows the text-align and the background property but not the line-height property.  If I click on the styles.css: 268 link in the inspector tool it takes me to the styles.css page and it clearly shows the line-height property set.

Why is the property not getting applied?  A class + element should have a higher specificity than an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

styles.css: 268 is `line-height = 1em;`
Should be `line-height:1em;`

Comment: Thanks that works - Its 3am.  Switching between programming languages and css is blurring.